# RX Java struggling to use map operator with a subset

Tags: arrays, json, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I'm new to RX and I've been using the map operator for a while. In my problem I'm transforming a collection of MovieEntity.class to a collection of Movie.class.

However this Movie.class comes with a list of integers as it's member indicating with genres this movie is related.

The classes looks like this:

```
public class MovieEntity{
   String name;
   List<Integer> genres;
}


public class Movie{
   String name;
   List<Genre> genres; 
}

public class Genre{
   String name;
   Integer id;
}


@Override
public Observable<List<Movie>> list() {
    return getDataSource()
            .movieList()
            .map(new Function<List<MovieEntity>, List<Movie>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Movie> apply(List<MovieEntity> movieEntities) throws Exception {
                    return movieMapper.transform(movieEntities);
                }
            });
}
```

I'm trying to find the best way to do convert the MovieEntity that contains just a list of integer ids, to Movie.class.

Of course I have a class that can map a reference of genre by its id.

If this is common and I should be searching with a specific term please don't hesitate to say it, because I'm kind confused.

Is there a standard way to solve this problem with RX?

Comment: What are the other methods on `getDataSource()`? Where do the list of `Genre` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Java Streams**:

```
public Observable<List<Movie>> list() {
    return getDataSource()
            .movieList()
            .map(movieList -> movieList.stream()
                    .map(movieEntity -> {
                        Movie movie = new Movie();
                        movie.name = movieEntity.name;
                        movie.genres = movieEntity.genres.stream()
                                .map(genreId -> genreMapper(genreId)) // your genre mapper
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        return movie;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );
}
```

---

**Using RxJava Observable**:

```
public Observable<List<Movie>> list() {
    return getDataSource()
            .movieList()
            .map(movieList -> Observable.fromIterable(movieList)
                    .map(movieEntity -> {
                        Movie movie = new Movie();
                        movie.name = movieEntity.name;
                        movie.genres = Observable.fromIterable(movieEntity.genres)
                                .map(genreId -> genreMapper(genreId)) // your genre mapper
                                .toList().blockingGet();
                        return movie;
                    })
                    .toList().blockingGet()
            );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is best solved outside of RxJava with traditional for loops (or Java Streams):

```java
Map<Integer, Genre> genresMap = ...

List<Movie> result = new ArrayList<Movie>();
for (MovieEntity entity : movieEntities) {
    Movie movie = new Movie();
    movie.name = entity.name;
    movie.genre = new ArrayList<Genre>();
    for (Integer genreId : entity.genre) {
        movie.genre.add(genresMap.get(genreId));
    }
}
return result;
```